# Jquery settimeout multiple times

Tags: jquery, settimeout

My problem is ... When i move mouse very fast many times on link, box just do not hide. It look like setTimeout is overwritten and old function stop working - and in final popup_remove() doesn't take place. Please help, I'm beginner in jQ and already lost almost two days with this hide and show box. Everything works greate when i do not use settimeout and just put display:none for mouseenter and mouseleave. I think I just do not understand setTimeout method.

My JS:

```
timeout_on = {};
timeout_off = {};

$('.flex_section').delegate('a','mouseenter mouseleave',function(e){
   var a = $(this).attr('id')
   if (e.type == 'mouseenter'){

     timeout_on['id_'+ a] = setTimeout(function() { popup_show(a); }, 300);

   } else {

     timeout_off['id_'+ a] = setTimeout(function() { popup_remove(a); }, 300)

   }
});

popup_show(type){
     $('#someID_' + type).css('display','block')
     clearTimeout(timeout_on['id_'+ type])
}
popup_remove(type){
     $('#someID_' + type).css('display','none')
     clearTimeout(timeout_off['id_'+ type])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must clear Timeout before set an other ??

mouse enter : 
 - add a timeout for entering
mouse leave :
 - delete old timeout
 - add a timeout for leaving 
...